# Can I set "Default branch for manual and scheduled builds" for a pipeline in Azure DevOps using an API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to set "Default branch for manual and scheduled builds" for a pipeline using the Azure DevOps REST API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you update a build with [Builds - Update Build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) Rest API you can send in the body the `repository` property, and inside it, you can set the `defaultBranch`:

```
repository: 
  checkoutSubmodules: false
  clean: "false"
  defaultBranch: "refs/heads/master"
  id: "7d9431dc-be40-48f6-a8dd-c12312424"
  name: "Test"
```

You can find all the repository options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/update%20build?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#buildrepository).